# Flask to android studio

Tags: android, python, flask

I'm currently having this problem for almost 8 hours now; I tried all the answers with the same problem that I'm with now but there is no solution found yet;

What I'm trying to do is that to contact the flask to android using URL's; since it is local I set the host already to '0.0.0.0' to be available globally and try this URL's to my android '10.0.2.2:5000', '10.0.3.2:5000', '192.168.X.X:5000', '127.0.0.1:5000', and allow my port to the firewall, and still nothing to work, I already search for all the same problem that I currently have and the solutions not working.

here is my python code:

```
#from app file

import os

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = b'MYKEY'

from blueprints import *

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
    return 'page not found', 404

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)

#from __init__ of blueprint

from app import app

from blueprints.routes.admin import admin_route
from blueprints.routes.android import android_route

app.register_blueprint(admin_route)
app.register_blueprint(android_route)


#from my routes where should android manipulate

from flask import Blueprint

android_route = Blueprint('android', __name__)

@android_route.route('/android/login')
def login():
    return 'hello'
```

And here is my android handling URLs:

```
package com.example.test.Link;

/*
*
*
* All link for contacting the server
* will be put here.
*
* */

public class UrlLink {

    private static final String API_TOKEN  = "1234567890";
    private static final String DOMAIN = "http://<I ALMOST TRY ALL IP>:5000";

    /*
        Links to use
     */

    public static final String login = DOMAIN  + "/android/login";
}
```

Also, I try to run this in PHP using xampp and works fine; but in the flask, it gives me an error of this:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.0.2.2:5000/android/login
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:206)
        at com.example.swiftpin.URL.Http.post(Http.java:61)
        at com.example.swiftpin.URL.ConnectHttp.doInBackground(ConnectHttp.java:88)
        at com.example.swiftpin.URL.ConnectHttp.doInBackground(ConnectHttp.java:15)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Did you check in the postman?

Comment: @Jaymin what is the help of postman regarding this problem?

Comment: It will tell whether you have issue with server or anything else.

Comment: @Jaymin do you have a link there? so that i could check.

Comment: Here it is : https://www.getpostman.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i found the solution, the only problem is that i'm a sending a post method which is not accepting in the python;

instead of this:

```
@android_route.route('/android/login')
def login():
    return 'hello'
```

I forgot to include a method there,
So it would be like this:

```
@android_route.route('/android/login', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    return 'hello'
```

I figure out this when I try to use a get method and it gives me a result but when I'm using post method nothing happens.